# Can't set headers after they are sent - inside looping

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

can someone help me to solve my piece of code.
I want to send data inside looping from nodejs API, after i send it error message appear "Can't set headers after they are sent".

..and this my code :

```
for (var i =0;i<req.body.stuff.length;i++){
 var arrStuff  = req.body.stuff[i];
 var getUrl    = 'https://someurl/' + arrStuff

 request.get(getUrl,
    function(error,response,body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200){

        rowData = JSON.parse(body)

        res.send(rowData) // send data to client

      }; // if (!error)

    } // function(error,response,body)
  ); // request.get(getUrl
```

..finally got error message like title above, because res.send has send twice ( inside looping ), and i dont know the best way to solve it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is someone is calling your API, then you are calling multiple APIs in loops, and you want to send that data to your API's caller.

You cannot `res.send` multiple times. Once thats executed, the API calling is finished. You have already send the reply.

The easiest way to achieve what you want is to store the responses you get in the loop in an outside array, then once all of the calls are done, send the array in `res.json` or `res.send`

Use [async.js](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html) to handle the looping. With `async.concat` you wont have to maintain the outside array yourself.

```
async.concat(req.body.stuff, function(arrStuff,callback){

 var getUrl    = 'https://someurl/' + arrStuff

 request.get(getUrl,
    function(error,response,body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200){

        rowData = JSON.parse(body)

        callback(null, rowData) // replace null by err to stop if err

      }; // if (!error)

    } // function(error,response,body)
  ); // request.get(getUrl

}, function(err, allData) {
    res.send(allData)
});
```

There are other ways like socket.io or something like a stream, but this is what you need.

Comment: ho ho..thanks so much Dushyant Bangal, it's working now, really really helpful. thanks..

Comment: you're welcome. Please check the tick to the left of my answer to "mark it as answer", might help someone else as well

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send multiple responses for a single request. **HTTP** follows **request-response pattern** Single response for a single request.

**Error: Can't set headers after they are sent**  means that you're already in the Body or Finished state, but some function tried to set a ***header*** or ***statusCode***. i.e ideally in your case is the **loop**